# Raise a python exception without "raise" statement

Tags: python, exception, raise

Is it possible to raise an exception in Python without using `raise` statement?

For example, instead of `raise ValueError` use some method like `ValueError.raise()`. This question only relates to python built-in exceptions and not some custom exception classes that can be build from them.

Comment: Raising is not something the exception does, it's something internal to the Python runtime, and the exception is just data that's passed along.

Comment: what kind of exception ? With a given message ?

Comment: Can you explain the motivation behind your question?

Comment: @azro Just any built-in exception with no parameters.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what exactly are your requirements? For example, would a function that internally `raise`s be suitable? What about running an expression that triggers the exception, for example `[][0]` to get an `IndexError`?

Comment: @C. Pappy I was wondering whether it'd be possible to pass an exception to another function as a callable (I ended up wrapping an exception in another function and using that as a callable).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi a function that raises an exception internally is exactly how I solved my problem. It just got me wondering if there is another way. Judging by the answers there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a helper function to raise the exception:

```
def raising(exc: BaseException):
    raise exc
```

This can then be used in any place an expression can be used, such as `lambda` or assignment expressions.

This approach can be used to make practically any statement usable as an expression. However, be mindful that statements are an important part of code readability - when in doubt, prefer to refractor the code so that the statement can be used in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can, just build a code that leads t generate an exception

- ZeroDivisionError

  ```
  print("x")
  1 / 0
  ```

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\test_4.py", line 9, in <module>
  1 / 0
  ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
  ```
- AssertionError

  ```
  print("x")
  assert 1 == 0, "custom message"
  ```

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\test_4.py", line 9, in <module>
  assert 1 == 0, "custom message"
  AssertionError: custom message
  ```
- ...